# Magento 1.9 Google Analytics acquisition not working

Tags: checkout, google-analytics

I'm running a Magento 1.9 store and have added the GA tracking code to the back end of Magento and this is tracking conversions just fine. To a degree.

While the code appears on the site when I place test orders correctly when I look in Analytics Conversions it's approximately 1/2 of what we would expect to see.

When trying to narrow down where the missing conversions were I was looking through acquisition and spotted a weird trend. The only channel we can see revenue for is the Referal channel.

Direct, Organic search, Social, Paid search and Email all have a number of sessions against them so standard tracking is recording them entering the site, but the only channel to display revenue is Referal.

To me this looks like something wrong with Magentos tracking code forgetting the user after they enter the site and thinking they're a referral user from them on. Does anyone have any insight on this issue?

**EDIT**

Looking at the aquisiiton breakdown on referrals also shows that checkout.sagepay.com and paypal.com are the only referrals with conversions with 0% new sessions

Comment: It might be showing because your site is redirecting to your payment gateway page and after taking payment coming back to your site. To resolve this issue you need to add your payment page domain in Referral Exclusion List in Google Analytics. Go to Google Analytics -> Admin -> Property (select your site) -> Tracking Info -> Referral Exclusion List. In regards to missing transactions, I would highly recommend to use the following module https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking-1.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the Tag Assistant on Chrome to see what information is send in every page? I use the Fooman extension that is working fine in 1.9